# 0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 Insufficient cpu. MR3 Hive

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, hive

I am trying to set up hive using mr3 on a kubernetes cluster hosted on AWS ec2. When I run the command run-hive.sh, Hive-server starts and the master-DAg is initialised but then it gets stuck on pending. When I describe the pod. This is the error message shows. I have kept the resources to minimum so it should not be that issue and I do not have any tainted nodes. If you know any alternative for running hive on Kubernetes with access to S3 or a better way to implement mr3 hive on Kubernetes cluster, please share.

[One of the node description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR8Pi.png)

Comment: Could You please add describe of your 3 nodes? Use `kubectl describe node <name>`, From the topic seems like 2 of you'r pods have not enough resources and 1 have taint which does not allow your pods to be created.

Comment: your issue is not because of the way you are installing Hive, but because you don't have enough resources. What nodes are you using? Have you investigated how much CPU and memory you need to run Hive or you just guessed?

Comment: Error message on question title `0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 Insufficient cpu.` clearly states you have Insufficient cpu and taint on one node and scheduler marks zero nodes as available out of three.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the topic i think the problem here is your cluster have not enough resources on your worker nodes, and a master node is [tainted](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/).

So the option here is either inreasing the resources on workers or taint the master node so You would be able to schedule pods there.

> Control plane node isolation
>
> By default, your cluster will not schedule pods on the control-plane node for security reasons. If you want to be able to schedule pods on the control-plane node, e.g. for a single-machine Kubernetes cluster for development, run:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

> This will remove the node-role.kubernetes.io/master taint from any nodes that have it, including the control-plane node, meaning that the scheduler will then be able to schedule pods everywhere

Comment: Hi @jt97, thanks for your response. The problem was as you described and the resources were lacking. Thanks for the answer.